# Saving animation from Blender and importing to Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I created a flag in Blender that moves in the wind by clicking alt+a (apparently that's not what I should click). But when I try to export it to Unity it doesn't save the animation.
How can I create the animation so it would save when moving it to Unity?

http://www.mediafire.com/download/g32rg7gi5gax191/flag.blend

Comment: You should provide some more information. What file formats are you using? That the animation in unity is not playing when clicking alt+a is clear I guess?

Comment: yes.
What more information do i need to give?
I just made an image like plane, made it cloth, and made wind to blow it.

Comment: That sounds like you just let the animation play in the blender game mode. You need to record the animation in order to get a keyframe based animation which is exportable. From the [Blender Manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Using_GE) I see, that you first need to select Game > Record Animation. Maybe you forgot this.

Comment: I made keyframes at the start and at the end.and the nimation in blender works.in unity doesnt.where is the Game menu?

Comment: I added my file. Can someone look and explain how to export it to unity

Comment: That most definitely is not a link to your file.

Comment: As far as I know a non-bone based deformation is simple not supported. So even if you would bake your cloth simulation, that wouldn't help you unless you write your own code for it.

Comment: How to write code  in unity (or in blender?) for the waving flag?